# Edit box scrolls back to the top after updating post

Tags: editor, post-editor, html-editor

I've been quite annoyed by this. On post edit page, once I edited something in the middle of the page and hit Update, the whole page reloads and the edit box starts from the top again and I have to scroll-and-search my last edited point.

Is there any workaround, solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of clean native solution, however there have been at least one plugin in the past [Save Editor Scroll Position](http://wordpress.org/plugins/save-editor-scroll-position/) (note - very outdated) trying to address this and might serve like prior art.

There is also open trac ticket [#18943 Scroll back to previous editor position after post save/update](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18943), however without patch suggestions or core developer feedback.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think this can be solved by plugin. I installed [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/preserve-editor-scroll-position) instead and it works